# EditText borders SDK >11

Tags: android

I've an activity with few EditTexts, it shows the underlying borders until no background is set. When I set a background for the whole LinearLayout, the EditText's highlighting gray borders go away. Only blue highlights appear when focussed.

How do I get those gray borders like in the screenshot below:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the theme in manifest does the trick:

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"
```